# Как заблокировать непонятные запросы из локальной сети в MikRotik

Tags: mikrotik

Не давно увидел в логах на MikRotik непонятные запросы из локальной сети в интернет, ip адрес не показан но показан mac адрес.
**Как определит и заблокировать ip адрес этого запроса, то есть сделать правило которое будет блокировать и заносить ip адрес в блек лист?**

```
576   Sep/20/2021 09:50:08   memory   firewall,info   forward: in:bridge out:pppoe-out1, src-mac 60:45:cb:aa:ec:5b, proto TCP (SYN), 169.254.101.248:62198->185.26.182.93:443, len 48
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В смысле «не показан»? А на скриншотах что?

Comment: @Alexey Ten То ip адрес внутренней сети (кабинета), идет перенаправление из сети кабинета через роутер (который в кабинете) в общую сеть на внешний роутер (интернет). Показывает не ip адрес роутера а его mac адрес

Comment: 20.20.10.100 и 169.254.101.248 - айпи адреса

Comment: а зачем их заносить в блек лист?

Comment: @eri Из за таких запросов гугл просит внести несколько раз рекапчу, это как-то поднадоело.

Comment: может лучше вылечить вирусы в сети?)